# CSS invalid property value for h4 margin

Tags: html, css, margin

I want to change matgins of an h4 element with styles.css

In the HTML file, the h4 is nested as this:

```css
main div h4 {
  margin: 20px, 0, 0, 0;
  /* want to change top margin */
}
```

```html
<main role="main" class="col-12 col-md-9 col-xl-8 py-md-3 pl-md-5">
  <div style="padding-top: 1.0rem;">
    <ul>...</ul>
    <h4 id='sec_summary'>Summary</h4>
  </div>
</main>
```

The other styles defined in styles.css work fine. But when I was trying to set h4 margin in the way shown above, I tried different numbers and units, the h4's margin doesn't change at all. Why doesn't the code work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove `,` :

```
main div h4 {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0; /* want to change top margin */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `,` from your `css` and put `space` instead

```
main div h4 {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0; /* want to change top margin */
  }
```

Comment: if this helped you, please consider accepting the answer :) @Robin

Comment: fyi simple typographical errors usually get deleted in due process. not worth it for an answer imo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove Commas (,) from your css and put ( )space

> You will define individual margin as follow:

```
  main div h4 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
     }
```

> You will use combine syntax as follow:

```
   main div h4 {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove **,** from your CSS margin code and place space between them like,

```
main div h4 {
  margin: 20px 0 0 0; 
}
```

**If the margin property has four values:**

```
top margin is 20px
right margin is 0px
bottom margin is 0px
left margin is 0px
```